# How to retrieve exact urls from a web page via java jsoup

Tags: java

I want to extract  urls of images from a web page. 
Related section's html format is as following :

```
<span class="news-img" style="background-image:url(https://theaddressofimage"></span>
```

and my code is like following :

```
Document pages = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(""+pages.select("span[style]"));
```

And the myoutput is containing all html elements  same as the format in above but my desire is to get only url not the whole element like https://theadressofimage.

I also used `attr()` or `absUrl()`; but did not help!

How can i get only the url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped to get exactly what i want

```
package getlink;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetLink {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String address = "http://interestedwebaddress/";

URL pageLocation =new URL(address);
Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());

while (in.hasNext()){
String line = in.next();

if (line.contains("thespecificexpressionthatlinklinecontains")){

int from = line.indexOf("(");
int to = line.lastIndexOf("\"");
System.out.println(line.substring(from +1, to-1)); //-1,+1 my case  specific
}
}
}
```